# Skipped review posts looping

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I am currently doing Low Quality Post reviews. Strangely, I seem to be in a rough loop where I can't skip beyond the same three or four posts:

[image: Same posts showing up when skipping]

I doubt this is client-side, but I'm using Firefox 90.8b8 on Arch Linux.

Comment: FWIW: I’m experiencing the same behavior—and, in fact, just came over to Meta to see if it had been reported yet (thank you for doing so). I am similarly curious whether it might be due to the scheduled maintenance.

Comment: I have the same behaviour - both on Chrome on Android 11, and Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: FWIW there was a change in the way how skipped posts are handled in LQ queue, [announced yesterday at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367908/165773)

Comment: This is related to my fix.  I'm investigating.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fixed.

[I shipped a change yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291299/unable-to-later-review-skipped-low-quality-posts-reviews-which-is-normally-allo/367908#367908) that allowed users to return to their skipped LQP tasks, and boy did I let them go back to them.

Basically, I fixed the "can a user review this post" sub-query to support returning to skipped posts, but the "give me the next post for a user" query was depending on that to exclude previously skipped tasks rather than including the default logic for that.

This problem was compounded for users with the trusted privilege, since if a post they can review has a recommend delete vote, they're only served review tasks with those votes. (Something similar happens with watched and ignored tags.) This meant instead of getting the skipped question 1 out of 125 times, you maybe got it one out of 5 times.

All queues now consistently filter out tasks you have reviewed in that queue instead of depending on the subquery to manage that exclusion.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks for the quick response! I was able to repro most easily with the Low Quality queue and have reached my daily cap there. Will try to repro after 0:00 UTC and then accept if I can't.

Answer (score 9):

Ah, it looks like some [scheduled maintenance](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1418889128612143111) [was](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1418919165952409602) [postponed](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1419777185443835921) [a few](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1420130631720194048) [times](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1420130631720194048) and is [likely ongoing](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1420535708578500613):

> We're starting the maintenance shortly and will have some instability during the work

I'll try again later.

**Edit:** This issue persists after the [maintenance was finished](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1420569302915235840). Brian Nickel [believes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409440/skipped-review-posts-looping?noredirect=1#comment857895_409440) that it is related to [a recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367908/248627) and is investigating.